# Tension in a rope

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Hello I was wondering if you guys can help me figure out how to calculate the tension (or weight) or a rope in a given system.

So A cylinder pipe that has outside diameter of 70cm (.7m) and inside of 60cm (.6) and ropes are split by a spreader bar at 45*. What is tension of AB and AC.

Kinda looks like this:

[image]

So I have $\pi(.7-.1)\cdot2320\cdot9.81= 9286\text{ N}$

Then after that I get confused what to do.

Comment: where did 2320 come from?

Comment: This looks like somebody's homework.

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: my guy, you must to sent us mass of payload. If mass not given, you must found it. How to found mass? U must find out, what material is this pipe?
If you know material, you can find density (even looking in wikipedia). Mass of pipe you can find by function: M = V* ρ where V is volume, ρ  - is density. Volume can be found like = (π*R*R - π*r*r)*L; L = 2,5 m; R = 0.7; r = 0.6; When you found out mass, you can found out tension in rope = mass/4 cause your system has symmetry. 
Sorry for my hard english.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin I don't think the tension it the rope is the same above and below the spreader (else the angle could not be 45 degrees). That said if cooper is confused calculating the weight he is a long way from worrying about the rope problem.

Comment: you right, it was joke) My answer under

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Copper density = 8.96 g/cube cm. It means, that Volume =  π*250 cm *(35cm*35cm - 30cm*30cm) ~   255 125 cube cm. 
   Of cource R = 0,5 D, formula for founding square = π(r**x**r);
   Mass = 255 125 cube cm* 8,96 g ~  2 285 920 g = 2,285 tons. 
   Force of weight = 2,285 * 9,8 * 1000  ~ 22 850 N.

[image]

1. Tension = mg/4  ~ 5712 Н cause you have 2 rope and two side.
2. Сhoose the axis like picture. **OY**||mg; **OX**⟂mg;
3. In accordance to second law of Newton, all strength in picture must be compensated (equal zero) in point **B.**

**Equations:**

**OY**: mg/4 = **Tr** * sin(45);  - therefore **Tr** = mg/(4*sin(45)) = 22 850/(4*0,7) ~ 8160 N ;

**OX**: Reactrion = Tr * cos(45) = 8 160 * 0,7 ~ 5712 N;

Thats All.